# Where can i get a live 13.04 image from

Tags: 13.04

i am installing Ubuntu Linux on my dads computer. i need a live disk image file for 13.04. i all ready have 10.04 installed,but i would like to be rid of that and have a boot able disk for 13.04.
where can i get one?

Comment: As always, you can download Ubuntu from http://ubuntu.com. Or, if you prefer, there are many third-party CD vendors that you can buy from.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu website has [a download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and a [guide for running the Ubuntu 13.04 Live CD.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)